# Google Analytics Android Sharedpreferences

Tags: android, google-analytics, sharedpreferences

I want to track some shared preference settings for all users of my app.  For example, I have one shared preference that's a boolean and I want the total number of users who have it set to true and the total that are set to false.  If a user switches the setting, I want it to reflect in Google Analytics.  From what I've gathered I need to set a custom dimension with a user based scope.

What I haven't been able to confirm is what would happen in the following scenario.  I have 10 users, 5 have the setting set to true and the other 5 to false.  If one of those users switch the preference from true to false, would Google Analytics report the total number of "true" users as 4 or 5?  I'm assuming the "false" users would report at 6 regardless.

The results I would want is the "true" users = 4 and the "false" users = 6.

1) Is this possible to accomplish?

2) If so, is this handled automatically at Google Analytics or do I need to manage it in my code?

The closest answer I could find was [How to track user preferences with Google Analytics for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598245/how-to-track-user-preferences-with-google-analytics-for-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics tracks "events" not "status" so there can be a lot of confusion. ("Behavior" is a series of events.) It also tracks things like "active users" but that isn't what you are trying to do.

Google gives you the ability to have events and also categorize and name them. So, essentially, you have a these options:

1. Download and track the data. You will need to track new installs vs. changes (of course).
2. Report each user's current status when they use it. You will then see "trends" based on who is using the app, but not necessarily changes.
3. If you have enough usage, just report the changes. it will tell you if users are trending toward one setting or another.

Personally, I track about 2,000 data points across about 50 apps and get a few million events daily. So if there is another way to more directly do what you want, I'd really like to know...

Comment: Ah gotcha, that's good to know.  If I find something else I'll post it here.  Thanks.